# formatting dates so users can read it iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert this

2015-05-16T08:00:00.000-07:00

into this format:
May 16th, 2015 7pm -8pm

Can you please show me how I can change it to the above format in objective C?

Thank you!

Comment: Please share your code so that i can help you.

Comment: 7pm-8pm what format is this? `07:00` seems time zone here

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use custom method to do this, Please check below method which may be help you -

```
-(NSString*) getDateTimeInString:(NSDate*)date
    {
        NSString* string=@"";
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:date];

        if(components.day == 1 || components.day == 21 || components.day == 31){
             string = @"st";
        }else if (components.day == 2 || components.day == 22){
            string = @"nd";
        }else if (components.day == 3 || components.day == 23){
             string = @"rd";
        }else{
             string = @"th";
        }

        NSDateFormatter *prefixDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    [prefixDateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];


        [prefixDateFormatter setDateFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MMM d'%@', yyyy hh a,string]];

        NSString *dateString = [prefixDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

        return dateString;
    }
```